# 2017 MacBook Pro - USB-C to Display-Port not working?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, thunderbolt, charging

Recently purchased a USB-C to HDMI cable for my 2017 13'' MacBook Pro with 4 Thunderbolt 3 ports. All was working well until I plugged in my charger and I noticed the charging icon flashing on and off, then I got the classic "USB Accessories Disabled" message, and the monitor stopped displaying. I couldnt' get the cable working again on any monitor so I gave up and decided to return it.

Today I decided to purchase a more expensive USB-C to DisplayPort adapter. Again, all was working well, so I assumed it was a dud cable. I plugged my charger in again and the same thing happened - monitor stopped working and the same "USB Accessories Disabled" message.

Just wondering if anyone has experienced any issue similar? It seems like it might be a fault with my laptop. I reset the SMC and PRAM but nothing changed. I've also noticed now that one of my USB-C ports is no longer working, which I'm not sure is related to this or not.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Grabbed a USB-C to USB-A adapter and tested the voltage on the back left port, and when the charger is plugged in the port outputs 20V, which explains the problems. Out of warranty so guessing I'm out of luck?

[image: Voltmeter]

Comment: I have heard (anecdotal) reports of the USB chips on MacBook logic boards failing - things from charging, to power delivery negotiation, to display issues.  This is not a software fix - you should take it in a get it looked at.

Comment: @Allan thank you, I assume since I'm well out of warranty I'm SOL?

Comment: Not necessarily. Contact [Rossman Group](https://rossmangroup.com) in NYC.  Probably one of the best board repair guys out there.  Not affiliated, just a happy customer.

Comment: Just saw your edit.  It  **shouldn't** be putting out 20V unless it was negotiated to do so. It should only be outputting 5V.  My guess is that it's the mux chip.